# How can I use git .mailmap to display the authors organizations?

Tags: git

The .mailmap file is used by git to normalize the authors / commiters names and emails. Could it also be used to show the organizations they belong to ?

Comment: Put organizations into commiters name

Answer (score 3):

The **.mailmap** file maps author names and email to a single canonical value. For instance, if **.mailmap** contains:

```
Chendi Xue <chendi.xue@intel.com> Chendi Xue <xuechendi@gmail.com>
```

the **git log --pretty='%aN <%aE>'** command will display **Chendi Xue <chendi.xue@intel.com>** instead of **Chendi Xue <xuechendi@gmail.com>**. Mapping authors to organizations can be done in another file, for instance **.organizationmap**.

The **git check-mailmap** command (requires git 1.9 or above) performs the same transformation **%aN <%aE>** does with **.mailmap** but with arbitrary files. For instance, to display the Intel organization instead of authors affiliated to Intel, the following **.organizationmap** file can be created:

```
Intel <contact@intel.com> Yuan Zhou <yuan.zhou@intel.com>
Intel <contact@intel.com> Chendi Xue <chendi.xue@intel.com>
```

and the **git log** command piped to the **git check-mailmap** command as follows:

```
$ git log --pretty='%aN <%aE>' | \
    git -c mailmap.file=.organizationmap check-mailmap --stdin
```

A leaderboard of commits per organizations can then be displayed by counting the number of lines:

```
$ git log --pretty='%aN <%aE>' | \
    git -c mailmap.file=.organizationmap check-mailmap --stdin | \
    sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | nl
...
6       748 Intel <contact@intel.com>
7       361 University of California, Santa Cruz <contact@cs.ucsc.edu>
8       248 UnitedStack <contact@unitedstack.com>
...
```

where the first column is the rank of the organization and the second column is the number of commits.